# CSS colors beside line numbers in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I really like how JetBrains in their apps (IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm, WebStorm etc.) show colors in the area next to line numbers for css element color declarations.

Is there such a plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: What you are looking for, add screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

Some color theme for Eclipse may help you,try this plugin:
https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme

Comment: Do any of the themes provide colors next to line numbers? I am not asking for syntax code highlighting.